# Detect when a webview video becomes fullscreen on ios8

Tags: ios, video, uiwebview, youtube, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have an app where users can open videos from UIWebview, including Youtube ones.
In iOS7, I was able to get a notification when it started playing, or when it became full screen, which is vital for me to show certain options to the user and modify the interface.

I used to use this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(VideoExitFullScreen:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification" object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(VideoEnterFullScreen:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification" object:nil];
```

However, since iOS8, I can't achieve this. It is like the notification is no longer triggered from UIWebview videos. However, it is still triggered from normal videos, non-Webview, as I've tested.

Any idea of what have changed?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is the work around I found for this..

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(VideoExitFullScreen:)
                                                 name:UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification
                                               object:self.view.window];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(VideoEnterFullScreen:)
                                                 name:UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification
                                               object:self.view.window];
```

Comment: I've found that **UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification** is called when video starts to play fullscreen. And **UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification** is called when video disappears.

Comment: I'm trying this in iOS 10 but these notifications never get called for me. Anyone else with the same problem?

Comment: @BerryBlue yep.  Same problem.  Did you ever find another way?

Comment: @BerryBlue remove the object:self.view.window, and replace with object: nil]

Answer (score 8):

Swift 5.1:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    forName: UIWindow.didResignKeyNotification,
    object: self.view.window,
    queue: nil
) { notification in
    print("Video is now fullscreen")
}

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    forName: UIWindow.didBecomeKeyNotification,
    object: self.view.window,
    queue: nil
) { notification in
    print("Video stopped")
}
```

Comment: Well it doesn't work ok for YouTube iFrame inside `UIWebView`. It always calls both events where it becomes fullscreen or exists fullscreen

Comment: because we should use `didBecomeVisibleNotification` and `didBecomeHiddenNotification`

Comment: Swift 5

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIWindow.didResignKeyNotification, object: self.view.window, queue: nil) { _ in
            print("Video is now fullscreen")
        }

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIWindow.didBecomeKeyNotification, object: self.view.window, queue: nil) { _ in
            print("Video stopped")
        }
```

Comment: Updated for swift 5

Answer (score 6):

update for Swift 4.2, iOS 12.1 and WKWebView:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // listen for videos playing in fullscreen
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onDidEnterFullscreen(_:)), name: UIWindow.didBecomeVisibleNotification, object: view.window)

    // listen for videos stopping to play in fullscreen
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onDidLeaveFullscreen(_:)), name: UIWindow.didBecomeHiddenNotification, object: view.window)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    // remove video listeners
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIWindow.didBecomeVisibleNotification, object: view.window)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIWindow.didBecomeHiddenNotification, object: view.window)
}

@objc func onDidEnterFullscreen(_ notification: Notification) {
    print("video is now playing in fullscreen")
}

@objc func onDidLeaveFullscreen(_ notification: Notification) {
    print("video has stopped playing in fullscreen")
}
```

Comment: The object: view.window sometimes will mean the notification will not be observed. We can pass nil for the object param, to always receive notifications.

Answer (score 2):

@NorthBlast's answer works well for detecting any `UIWindow` appearing on top of the `UIViewController` that holds the `UIWebView`. Unfortunately, it's hard to filter what kind of `UIWindow` is (since, well... you can't really know if it is a video or some other kind of window).

There are 3 special cases I prefer to filter, in which you're sure they are **NOT** video player windows, those are:

1) `_UIAlertControllerShimPresenterWindow`, which is a kind of window that appears when using alerts (like `UIAlertView`).

2) `UITextEffectsWindow`, which appears when presenting special iOS windows (like the share window, `UIActivityViewController`).

3) `UIRemoteKeyboardWindow` which appears when presenting the keyboard (for some reason, this class only appeared to me when using Swift, but on Objective-C it didn't... no clue why is that).

So to subscribe to notifications, I use (just like @NorthBlast said):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(windowDidBecomeActive:)
                                             name:UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(windowDidBecomeHidden:)
                                             name:UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Then the implementations:

```
- (void)windowDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if ( [self isVideoPlayerWindow:notification.object] ) {
        // Do what's needed if it is a video
        // For example, on a live streaming radio app, I would stop the audio if a video is started
    }
}

- (void)windowDidBecomeHidden:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if ( [self isVideoPlayerWindow:notification.object] ) {
        // Do what's needed if it is a video
    }
}

- (BOOL)isVideoPlayerWindow:(id)notificationObject {
    /*
     Define non video classes here, add more if you need it
    */
    static NSArray *nonVideoClasses = @[
        @"_UIAlertControllerShimPresenterWindow",
        @"UITextEffectsWindow",
        @"UIRemoteKeyboardWindow"
    ];

    BOOL isVideo = YES;
    for ( NSString *testClass in nonVideoClasses ) {
        isVideo = isVideo && ! [notificationObject isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(testClass)];
    }

    return isVideo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For swift:

`NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(xxx), name: NSNotification.Name.MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreen, object: nil)`

Comment: This will no longer work for iOS 9, etc. It's now deprecated.