# Capturing fullscreen event for fullscreen Youtube iFrame and do the fullscreen programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, youtube-api

I embedded a YouTube iFrame with iFrame API into a `UIWebView` to play videos. Here's the HTML script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; width:100%; height:100%; }
        html { width:100%; height:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script type='text/javascript' src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api" ></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var player;
    YT.ready(function() {
      player = new YT.Player('player', {
  "playerVars" : {
    "enablejsapi" : 1,
    "modestbranding" : 1,
    "autoplay" : 1,
    "showinfo" : 1,
    "controls" : 1,
    "playsinline" : 1,
    "autohide" : 0
  },
  "width" : "100%",
  "videoId" : %@,
  "events" : {
    "onPlaybackQualityChange" : "onPlaybackQualityChange",
    "onStateChange" : "onStateChange",
    "onError" : "onPlayerError",
    "onReady" : "onReady"
  },
  "height" : "100%"
});
      window.location.href = 'ytIosPlayer://onYouTubeIframeAPIReady';
             });
    function onReady(event) {
        window.location.href = 'ytIosPlayer://onReady?data=' + event.data;
    }
    function onStateChange(event) {
        window.location.href = 'ytIosPlayer://onStateChange?data=' + event.data;
    }

    function onPlaybackQualityChange(event) {
        window.location.href = 'ytIosPlayer://onPlaybackQualityChange?data=' + event.data;
    }
    function onPlayerError(event) {
        window.location.href = 'ytIosPlayer://onError?data=' + event.data;
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It is named "youtubeEmbedHtml.html" will be used in a class called `YoutubeIosPlayerView` that will have the UIWebView that will be used to embed the video. This is the code:

```
@implementation YoutubeIosPlayerView

@synthesize webView;

- (void)loadVideo:(NSString*)youtubeID
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"youtubeEmbedHtml"
                                                     ofType:@"html"
                                                inDirectory:@"Assets"];
    NSString *embedHTMLTemplate =
        [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    NSString *embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTMLTemplate, youtubeID];

    //NSLog(@"YTPlayer embed HTML: %@", embedHTML);
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]];
    [self.webView setDelegate:self];
    self.webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
    self.webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;

}

-(void)playVideo
{
    NSLog(@"Video Played!");
    [self stringFromEvaluatingJavaScript:@"player.playVideo();"];
}

- (void)pauseVideo
{
    NSLog(@"Video Paused!");
    [self stringFromEvaluatingJavaScript:@"player.pauseVideo();"];
}

- (void)stopVideo
{
    NSLog(@"Video Stopped!");
    [self stringFromEvaluatingJavaScript:@"player.stopVideo();"];
}

- (void)clearVideo
{
    [self stringFromEvaluatingJavaScript:@"player.clearVideo();"];
}


- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{

    NSString* currentURL = self.webView.request.URL.absoluteString;
    NSLog(@"shouldStartLoadWithRequest: URL string = %@\n", currentURL);

    if ([request.URL.scheme isEqual:@"ytIosPlayer"])
    {
        NSString *action = request.URL.host;

        NSString *query = request.URL.query;
        NSString *data;
        if (query)
        {
            data = [query componentsSeparatedByString:@"="][1];
        }

        if ([action isEqual:@"onReady"])
        {
            if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(playerViewDidBecomeReady:)])
            {
                [self playVideo]; //Play video if it's successfully loaded
            }
        }
        else if ([action isEqual:@"onStateChange"])
        {
            if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(playerView:didChangeToState:)])
            {

                if ([data isEqual:@"0"])
                {
                    [self loadNextVideo]; //Load the next video automatically when the current video stops playing
                }
            }
        }

        return NO;
    }
    else if ([request.URL.scheme isEqual: @"http"] || [request.URL.scheme isEqual:@"https"])
    {
        return [self handleHttpNavigationToUrl:request.URL];
    }
    return YES;
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString* currentURL = self.webView.request.URL.absoluteString;
    NSLog(@"webViewDidFinishLoad: URL string = %@\n", currentURL);
    NSString* location = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location"];
    NSLog(@"webViewDidFinishLoad: Location string = %@\n", location);
    NSString* html = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];
    NSLog(@"webViewDidFinishLoad: inner HTML string = %@\n", html);
    NSLog(@"--------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
}
```

Now, the code is actually working quite well. But due to some circumstances, I need to be able to capture the event when the user is clicking the fullscreen button and whether or not the player is playing at fullscreen. Also I need to be able to do the fullscreen programmatically from the app instead of clicking the fullscreen button in iFrame. Can anybody tell me how to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for Capturing fullscreen event in iOS 8, RF: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26068475/1083128