# iOS hotspot messes with fullscreen video player status bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, html5-video

When I open video from `UIWebView` while Personal Hotspot(blue status bar) is enabled, video player does not go fullscreen, it leaves 20px above empty and makes it transparent.

Is there a way to fix it? I'm not even sure if I can detect the presented video VC from `UIWebView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks. Well, it helped, but had to add observers from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766365/detect-when-a-webview-video-becomes-fullscreen-on-ios8