# How to receive Notification in UIWebView Player for full screen mode in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, uiwebview, video-player

I want to do some stuff after video playing in full screen mode in UIWebView.
So, I want message from `UIWebView` for entering in full screen & exit from full screen.

In iOS 7 I am getting notification by below stuff:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(VideoEnterFullScreenHere:)
                                             name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification"
                                           object:self.view.window];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(VideoExitFullScreenHere:)
                                             name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification"
                                           object:self.view.window];
```

But in iOS 8, it is not working properly.

Comment: is there a possibility that `self.view.window` may be pointing to something else in iOS8 than the one in iOS7? Did you try setting `object` to `nil` so notification sent by any object will be received?

Comment: @ozgur, Hi, It doesn't make any effect.

Comment: have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25561812/uimovieplayercontrollerdidenterfullscreennotification-not-work-in-ios8?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect when a webview video becomes fullscreen on ios8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766365/detect-when-a-webview-video-becomes-fullscreen-on-ios8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below stuff is worked for me.
I hope it will help others!

In your AppDelegate.m class,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(windowBecameHidden:) name:UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification object:nil];

    return YES;
}
```

And receive it by this,

```
- (void)windowBecameHidden:(NSNotification *)notification {

    UIWindow *window = notification.object;

    if (window != self.window) {
        NSLog(@"Online video on full screen.");
    }
}
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Use AVPlayer Notification instead of UIMoviePlayer Notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playerItemInitiated:)
                                                 name:@"AVPlayerItemBecameCurrentNotification"
                                               object:nil];
```

Comment: still working on iOS 10.3 with UIWebView，but not working with WKWebView.

Comment: any solution for this you can give me suggestion on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377677/how-to-detect-avplayer-and-get-url-of-current-video-from-wkwebview

Comment: can you find this observer in WKWebView ? please help me i'm still searching.