# How to intercept video when going to fullscreen in a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, video, uiwebview

I'm trying to add a button to the video player that gets added to the view when a video becomes fullscreen from inside of an embedded web browser.

I saw this: [Detect when a webview video becomes fullscreen on ios8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766365/detect-when-a-webview-video-becomes-fullscreen-on-ios8). However, I think at that point we won't have a pointer to the video player. Perhaps there's a way to loop through all the subviews of the window's view and grab whatever is an instance of AVPlayer?

Ideally I could do something like this:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(
    UIWindowDidResignKeyNotification,
    object: self.view.window,
    queue: nil
) { notification in
    let window = whatever the window is now
    let player = window.methodThatReturnsVideoPlayer
    // do stuff with player
    let button = UIButton(...)
    window.view.addSubView(button)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public API method to get a pointer to the video player in a `UIWebView`.

There is, however, an unsafe way to access the video player.  Using reflection, you can iterate through the subviews of a `UIWebView` and attempt to find the player:

```
- (UIView *)getViewInsideView:(UIView *)view withPrefix:(NSString *)classNamePrefix {
    UIView *webBrowserView = nil;
    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
        if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) hasPrefix:classNamePrefix]) {
            return subview;
        } else {
            if((webBrowserView = [self getViewInsideView:subview withPrefix:classNamePrefix])) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return webBrowserView;
}

- (UIViewController *)movieControllerFromWebView:(UIWebView *)webview {
    UIViewController *movieController = nil;
    @try {
        UIView *movieView = [self getViewInsideView:webview withPrefix:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"MP%@oView", @"Vide"]];
        SEL mpavControllerSel = NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"mp%@roller", @"avCont"]);
        if ([movieView respondsToSelector:mpavControllerSel]) {
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
            movieController = (UIViewController *)[movieView performSelector:mpavControllerSel];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to get movieController: %@", exception);
    }

    return movieController;
}
```

This code has been adopted from [YouTubeHacks.m](https://gist.github.com/romainbriche/2308668).

Your milage may vary, as Apple tends to change the name of their player objects with the different SDKs (`MPMoviePlayerController`, `UIMovieView`, `MPVideoView`, `UIMoviePlayerController`, etc.).  I would look at the [MediaPlayer.framework private headers](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/tree/master/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework) for reference.

Comment: would there be an easier way to add buttons to all full screen video players?

Comment: @Edmund How would you do this?  The implementation of the full screen players is private to Apple, there's no way to magically "add buttons" to all players without modifying the underlying implementation.

Comment: I was thinking of using the `UIWindowDidResignKeyNotification` event and then looping through the views of the controller of that window and then using `addSubview(button)` but i don't know how to find the views of the current `window`

Comment: @Edmund `UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows` or `UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow`?

Comment: `UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow` is the current active window right? how would i loop through its views and find the one that is a video player?

Comment: @Edmund `UIWindow` inherits from `UIView`.  Just use the window's `subviews` property.

Comment: ooo after that how would i find the viewplayer specifically?? I want to do something like `currentWindow.subviews.find(video player).addSubviews(button)`

Comment: @Edmund Use the code I provided in my answer looking for one of the classes I listed.  Once you have a reference to the video view, add the button as subview to that view.